# $(1-e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n} })(1-e^{\frac{4\pi i}{n} })...(1-e^{\frac{(n-1)2\pi i}{n} })=n$ for each natural $n\geq 2$.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

So let $n\geq 2$ and I want to show that

$$\left(1-e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n} }\right)\left(1-e^{\frac{4\pi i}{n} }\right)\dots\left(1-e^{\frac{(n-1)2\pi i}{n} }\right)=n,
$$

How do I go about it? Induction is not really going to work here, since factors depend on $n$ as well. I have tried grouping factors in a different way and expanding but this also leads to nowhere.

Comment: Why does it matter if the factors depend on $n$?

Comment: the statement for $n$ cannot be obtained by simply multiplying the statement for $n-1$ by an additional factor, because all the factors for $n$ and $n-1$ would be different.

Comment: Replace $1$ with $X$. Multiply with $X - 1$. Look at the polynomial you get. Divide by $X - 1$, you now know what the resulting polynomial is. Plug in $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_k=e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n} }$ be root of $x^n=1$. Then
$$
\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x-x_k)=x^n-1
$$
Note that $x_0=1$. So
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(x-x_k)=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}=1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}
$$
Set $x=1$ and we have
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}})=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-x_k)=n
$$